# Jmeter not starting up while excuting command as non-root user

Tags: permissions, java, environment-variables, user-profile

I'm able to start jmeter form ubuntu 16.10 terminal as root user. However,  If I try to start up jmeter using non-root user by executing the same command as in tried for root. I'm getting the following error. Can someone help me to fix the issue for existing non-root user (Not a sudo user)

```
user@laptop1:~$jmeter
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConversionException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:328)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:262)
JMeter home directory was detected as: /usr/share/jmeter
```

The error seems to be related to an unsupported JAVA version (Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 ). But you can see the supported JAVA version 8 is already configured in alternatives

```
update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

 Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
 -----------------------------------------------------------
0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java   2         manual mode     
2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode
* 3          /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

guest@duriel:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 27  2015 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb  9 09:43 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
$ ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6456 Jan 24 14:22 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
$ update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Comment: What's the output of `which java` vs. `sudo which java`?

Comment: If you still have this issue, responding to requests for more information is the best approach to getting it resolved. If you've managed to resolve it please provide an answer so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] the output of the command `ll /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java ` into your post along with the output of the commands that @DavidFoerster requested. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Added the requested info. For me, it behaves the same as root and non-root (sudo which java outputs the same)

Comment: @DavidFoerster - First of all thank you for responding back to my question.

Comment: @ElderGeek - I posted the question a couple of months back. I was not getting a response during I faced the issue. Later I fixed the issue by myself, I couldn't add the fix here at that time.  I'm trying to get the solution added here soon which may definitely help others too.

Comment: @cinny can't you edit it in the original question?

Comment: @Elwhis -   Please find output asked of ll  below (Note this may be a different ouput while I had the issue ).                                                                           ll /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7734 Nov 14 20:39 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java*

Comment: @cinny ok, but how did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: @Elwhis - If i'm not wrong I followed the issue mention here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: @Elwhis - Respond back if  this helps you fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is not the result of testing, just research. Constructive criticism to this answer is welcome as are tested solutions.

Generally Speaking:

This error appears to occur due to a mismatch between the version of Java (JDK) used a compile time and the version of Java available at runtime or when several versions are installed simultaneously (as appears to be the case here).

You can check and compare the versions with for the compiler

```
javac -version
```

and the runtime with

```
java -version
```

To fix the actual problem you should try to either run the Java code with a newer version of Java JRE or specify the target parameter to the Java compiler to instruct the compiler to create code compatible with earlier Java versions.

There are several ways to resolve this it seems to boil down to whether you want to approach it by insuring that code will be run by the right JRE or insuring that the code is compatible with currently used JRE.

For the former, one example solution is to change the symbolic link (/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java) to the version used for compilation.

For the latter, a solution is to generate new class files compatible with an earlier runtime version of Java you are attempting to use by Utilizing Cross-compilation options. For example to generate class files compatible with  Java 1.4, use the following command line:

javac -target 1.4 HelloWorld.java

Specifically speaking:

Whether you are rolling your own or using a pre-built binary of Jmeter downloaded from [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) it's important to [verify the integrity.](http://www.apache.org/info/verification.html)]

Note that Jmeter 3.1 Requires Java 7 or later so it *should* be working with your Java 8 but since you aren't running MAC OSX there's no [reason not to try it with Java 7](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

Another possible solution is to correct the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

With

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/javac/

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath

https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: (I guess) I managed to fix it by setting JAVA_HOME. Did also some different stuff, so not sure if it was that. Anyways I am giving you the bounty at least for the effort to help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Elwhis Thank you. I've expanded my answer to cover that possibility in the hope that it will prove useful to others.